# c# Html Agility pack getting div and span nodes

Tags: c#, html

This is the html document I am trying to extract the highlighted data in

[image: Screen shot of html source code].

I have read a lot on this site but was unable to find a solution that was helpful. 
I tried using

```
    nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(table_title + "/tbody/tr/td");
    headers = nodes.Elements("span").Select(d => d.InnerText.Trim());
    foreach (var this_header in header)
    {
       string location = this_header.InnerText.Trim();
       Console.Writeline(location);
    }
```

This does not give me the correct information. How do I find the specific content I am looking for?

Comment: Why not select on the class `today_nowcard-location` or is that used elsewhere?

Comment: headers = nodes.Elements("/h1[@class = 'today_nowcard-location']").Select(d => d.InnerText.Trim()); like that? I get an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You'd need to start your xpath with `//` not `/` so it will search more than one level deep.  Also you should be able to do that directly on the `doc.DocumentNode` because I don't see any tables in your example.

Comment: I tried that i got the error Value can not be null

Answer (score 0):

What is this /tbody/tr/td ... there is no table at all.

you have to get a unique selector (xpath, css, id) at SelectNodes..

Comment: I have tried that but I had trouble getting an effective xpath

Comment: Is it a repeating element or always one?